# Looping over all databases in a directory

Tags: vb6, iteration

I need to loop over all databases in a certain directory, where the database name is `ACPwxyz.mdb`, where wxyz is the equivalent to an MMYY value for the period that database was used for.

E.g., the database for July 2017 would be ACP0717.mdb.

I've never written in VB6 before and I totally hate it, but it's an extension to an existing project so I'm stuck with it!

Is there a way of looping over all files in a directory, checking if the file name follows the format of `ACPwxyz.mdb` or not, and if it does, then opening a connection to it?

I've looked around a bit and see `Dir(x, y)`, but I'm not sure if I can use this in this situation?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Hire a VB6 programmer.

Comment: Agree with @Bob77.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dir`, yes.

If you use something like this:

```
Dim strFile As String
strFile = Dir(yourDBPath, "ACP????.mdb") ' mdb for MS-Access files

Do Until strFile = ""
 If Len(strFile) = 11 Then ' Ensure the DB file name is 11 characters, which yours are

   'Do something // You can also check the file name doesn't = a certain name if needed

 End If

 strFile = Dir
Loop
```

`Dir` accepts either an asterisk (*), or a question mark (?) as wildcards in file names, so this will look for any database in  the set path that is called `ACP` followed by 4 characters.